# Ubuntu 18.04 UFW setup

Tags: ubuntu, ufw

I have one application running on two ports `HTTP` on `8080` and `HTTPS` on `8443`.

I want everyone to have access to port `8443` and whitelist `8080` to an IP, so only a particular IP can access the port.
So I have set up UFW firewall for the same :

```
sudo ufw enable
sudo ufw allow from 10.11.111.11 to any port 53 proto udp
```

My service on `10.11.111.11` is running on port 8080 do we need define port also ?

Currently I can not connect to port 8080 using the above IP and how to open port `8443` to everyone ?